# SQL Many to Many - Very simple

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have three tables

student:
id int (pk),
name varchar(255)

discipline:
id int (pk),
name varchar(255)

student_discipline:
student_id int,
discipline_id int

I know that this has something to do with many-to-many relationship, and more than one joins are necessary, but i'm very new to sql, so my question is:

How can i make a query that returns only students with 'John' as starting name that have 'Math' as discipline, but only the student id and the student name, for example ?

Any help is appretiated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Student tp
JOIN Student_Discipline tpt on tpt.sID = tp.sID
JOIN Discipline t on tpt.dID = t.dID
WHERE tp.Name like 'John%' and t.Name = 'Math'
```

Comment: What are the square brackets for? This is MySQL, not SQL-Server.

Comment: thanks man, how would be to return only the id and name of the student ?

Comment: nevermind dumb question, SELECT tp.id_aluno, tp.nome  FROM alunos tp

Comment: Return id & name of student:

SELECT tp.sID, tp.Name FROM Student tp
JOIN Student_Discipline tpt on tpt.sID = tp.sID
JOIN Discipline t on tpt.dID = t.dID
WHERE tp.Name like 'John%' and t.Name = 'Math'